# Unable to solve error " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o "

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I am currently practicing using Javascript/Dojo. However, I have an error that I am unable to solve:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

I have made a quick snippet of my problem:

```
var data = {
    "list": {
        "1": {
            "Relevance": "Low",
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Inorganic"
        },
        "2": {
            "Relevance": "Low",
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "Mobile"
        }
    }
}

var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(jsonData.list[1].Name);
```

It specifically targets the line with:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

I would like to know why this is an error & how I would solve it.

Comment: This question has been asked [several times](https://www.google.com/#q=uncaught+syntaxerror+unexpected+token+o) already.  A possible duplicate is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're trying to parse a JavaScript object. `JSON.parse` is for parsing a JSON string *representing* a JavaScript-like object.

Just skip the parsing altogether:

```
alert(data.list[1].Name);
```

---

On a related note: you might be interested in reading **[There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)**.

Answer (score 4):

Error is once declared as datatype json, it parses for you.

so : it would be something like this

```
<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">var obj = JSON.parser(data)</span>

 success: function(data){

  var obj = JSON.parser(data)

  alert(obj.data)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
 alert(data.list[1].Name);
```

instead of:

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
 alert(jsonData.list[1].Name);
```

data is already a javascript object not a string

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are parsing a plain object, and not a string, as expected.
In this case you just have to:

```
alert(jsonData.list[1].Name);
```

In this case, to use the `JSON.parse` method you should've been using this string:

```
var stringifiedJson = var data = "{"+
    "\"list\": {"+
        "\"1\": {"+
            "\"Relevance\": \"Low\","+
            "\"id\": 1,"+
            "\"Name\": \"Inorganic\""+
        "},"+
        "\"2\": {"+
            "\"Relevance\": \"Low\","+
            "\"id\": 2,"+
            "\"Name\": \"Mobile\""+
        "}"+
    "}"+
"}";

var jsonData = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson);
alert(jsonData.list[1].Name);
```

I recommend you to take a look at [this MDN article about native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON)