# Reading Values of JSON Message

Tags: javascript, json

I have been struggling with a few lines of Javascript code which should be straightforward. I have reduced my JSON String to the one found hereafter. The first alert in the code hereafter generates the following message:

{"list":[{"text":"Text1", "created_at":"Date1"},{"text":"Text2", "created_at":"Date2"}]}

However, the second alert generates the following error in IE:
Error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

```
var data = "{\"list\":[{\"text\":\"Text1\", \"created_at\":\"Date1\"},{\"text\":\"Text2\", \"created_at\":\"Date2\"}]}";
alert(data);
alert(data.list[0].created_at);
```

Would anyone understand why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 3):

`data` is an ordinary string; it doesn't have any properties.

You want to parse the JSON in the string into a Javascript object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was initially parsing the string as you have suggested, but was obtaining another error. Therefore, I had found the following answer at the link hereafter which appeared to suggest the opposite, and thus had removed the parsing altogether.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265929/unable-to-solve-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o
I guess I hadn’t interpreted that answer correctly. I believe that my initial error was related to the format of the JSON Object itself.
Thank you again.

Comment: @JF0001: It sounds like you were calling `JSON.parse()` on an object, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a string with Json formatting, but is not JSON itself.

You should use this:

```
var data = {"list":[{"text":"Text1", "created_at":"Date1"},{"text":"Text2", "created_at":"Date2"}]};
alert(data.list[0].created_at);
```

Or use:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(jsonData.list[0].created_at);
```