# Error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with JSON.parse"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What causes this error on the third line?

```js
var products = [{
  "name": "Pizza",
  "price": "10",
  "quantity": "7"
}, {
  "name": "Cerveja",
  "price": "12",
  "quantity": "5"
}, {
  "name": "Hamburguer",
  "price": "10",
  "quantity": "2"
}, {
  "name": "Fraldas",
  "price": "6",
  "quantity": "2"
}];
console.log(products);
var b = JSON.parse(products); //unexpected token o
```

<sup>Open console to view error</sup>

Comment: You don't have any JSON? It's an array/object literal.

Comment: Sidenote: I noticed that if you use JQuery and get a JSON string by the data-attribute e.g. `$('#mydata').data('person');` then JQuery turns the data string into a JSON object by itself. Here is no need to use `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

`products` is an object.  (creating from an object literal)

`JSON.parse()` is used to convert a **string** containing JSON notation into a Javascript object.

Your code turns the object into a string (by calling `.toString()`) in order to try to parse it as JSON text.
The default `.toString()` returns `"[object Object]"`, which is not valid JSON; hence the error.

Comment: is it not an Array? Why is it an object. Objects start with { and arrays start with [? or am i false here

Comment: Arrays are objects; that's what `.toString()` returns (as per the spec).

Comment: Is the solution to stringify the object first?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: No; the solution is to do nothing and use your object.

Comment: What if I get my data from a remote service using Ajax, which gives me Json response back? And I want that response to be saved in JavaScript array object?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: If you have an object, you don't need to parse it..  If you have string, you won't get an error.

Comment: I don't really see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin To clarify, what you're asking is the opposite situation as the person asking this question. If what you received from the service is a JSON-encoded string, you should use `JSON.parse(theString)` to parse that string into whatever it represents (which may be an array, string, any valid JSON value). The person asking this question already has an object; there is no JSON in their situation so using `JSON` at all will not help them.

Answer (score 165):

Let's say you know it's valid JSON, but you’re are still getting this...

In that case, it's likely that there are hidden/special characters in the string from whatever source your getting them. When you paste into a validator, they are lost - but in the string they are still there. Those characters, while invisible, will break `JSON.parse()`.

If `s` is your raw JSON, then clean it up with:

```
// Preserve newlines, etc. - use valid JSON
s = s.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
// Remove non-printable and other non-valid JSON characters
s = s.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]+/g,"");
var o = JSON.parse(s);
```

---

Updated a decade later - the control range is `\u0000-\u001F` - fixed...

The formal spec is here: https://www.json.org/json-en.html
The reason we preserve the white space and other chars is that the spec allows it and it ensures your white space char is encoded correctly.

Should you accept invalid JSON? It's up to you. But sometimes we got work to do and want to move on.

Comment: Got a trailing special character after Base64 decoding, your method helped me a lot! Thx

Comment: don't trust a source responding with invalid JSON. Just inform them that the data is corrupt. they should fix it. if you try to "recover" the response like this or in similar ways, you'll be keeping an unstable communication.

Comment: Should be `s = s.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]+/g,""); ` instead of `s = s.replace(/[\u0000-\u0019]+/g,""); `, for replacing all the control characters. Right?

Comment: what is the logic behind  `s.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")  `   I tested that, it applies to e.g. `"abc\\ndef".replace(/\\n/g,"\\'");`  it'd turn it into `abc\'def`  why do you want to do that?  Does json not allow ending a line with a backslash.. can you comment a bit about what your examples do and why

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. Especially when you copy JSON to clipboard and there were hidden special endline characters in the console.

Comment: I have valid json `{"comment": "fixes\n"}` 
and I am trying to parse it `JSON.parse('{"comment": "fixes\n"}')`
Console returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ` even though it is valid json. Could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 82):

It seems you want to **stringify** the object, not parse. So do this:

```
JSON.stringify(products);
```

The reason for the error is that `JSON.parse()` expects a `String` value and `products` is an `Array`.

*Note: I think it attempts `json.parse('[object Array]')` which complains it didn't expect token `o` after `[`.*

Comment: Worked for me. I stringified all array elements and array itself. Then json.parse() was successful.

Comment: Why would you do this though? It's already an object. Why stringify it only to parse it back to an object again?

Comment: @Clonkex to write it to a file, to post as text, to print on the document, to make a string search, to persist in a database, to debug, to make fun of it and a few other reasons...

Comment: My point is that you wouldn't `stringify` and then immediately `parse`. That would be pointless (unless you're trying to do a deep copy or something weird like that). Maybe you're saying to replace `parse` with `stringify`, but it sounds like you're saying to first `stringify` so that the `parse` works (which, as I say, would be pointless).

Comment: I don't know how you got "first stringify" from the answer but added "not parse" to be clear..

Answer (score 38):

JSON.parse is waiting for a String in parameter. You need to stringify your JSON object to solve the problem.

```
products = [{"name":"Pizza","price":"10","quantity":"7"}, {"name":"Cerveja","price":"12","quantity":"5"}, {"name":"Hamburguer","price":"10","quantity":"2"}, {"name":"Fraldas","price":"6","quantity":"2"}];
console.log(products);
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));  //solves the problem
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Comment: This is simple and straight forward and simply talks with code syntax. tnx

Answer (score 33):

I found the same issue with `JSON.parse(inputString)`.

In my case, the input string is coming from my server page *(return of a page method)*.

I printed the `typeof(inputString)` - it was string, but still the error occurs.

I also tried `JSON.stringify(inputString)`, but it did not help.

Later I found this to be an issue with the new line operator `[\n]`, inside a field value.

I did a *replace (with some other character, put the new line back after parse)* and everything was working fine.

Comment: The new line character was also my problem. So how can we restore such data?

Comment: @kolenda You have invalid JSON.  You need to change your server to use an actual JSON serializer that returns valid JSON.

Comment: I had a similar issue but instead of "\n" I had a "\e" inside a path (I changed the server side code to use "/" instead of "\" and everything was working again)

Comment: use an escape wherein \n would be \\n

Comment: I replaced it with <br> - worked for me - data = data.replaceAll('\n','\\u003cbr\\u003e')

Answer (score 21):

You should validate your JSON string [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

A valid JSON string must have double quotes around the keys:

```
JSON.parse({"u1":1000,"u2":1100})       // will be ok
```

If there are no quotes, it will cause an error:

```
JSON.parse({u1:1000,u2:1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
```

Using single quotes will also cause an error:

```
JSON.parse({'u1':1000,'u2':1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

Comment: In my case, Grails 2.5.6 rendered `render ([key: value])` with single quotes, leading to the JSON parseError at position 1 in jquery Ajax. `render (groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson ([key:value]))` helped me out.

Answer (score 14):

```
products = [{"name":"Pizza","price":"10","quantity":"7"}, {"name":"Cerveja","price":"12","quantity":"5"}, {"name":"Hamburguer","price":"10","quantity":"2"}, {"name":"Fraldas","price":"6","quantity":"2"}];
```

change to

```
products = '[{"name":"Pizza","price":"10","quantity":"7"}, {"name":"Cerveja","price":"12","quantity":"5"}, {"name":"Hamburguer","price":"10","quantity":"2"}, {"name":"Fraldas","price":"6","quantity":"2"}]';
```

Comment: @SLaks yep,OP can use products directly. but if he want use `JSON.parse`, the args need be a string.

Comment: what should i do in ASP Classic because ' is comment

Comment: @ashishbhatt you can use ", then change all other " to \"

Comment: Something like this `JSON.parse(products.replace(/'/g, '"'))`

Comment: What is the gist of it? What is the conclusion? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14432177/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

If there are leading or trailing spaces, it'll be invalid.
Trailing and leading spaces can be removed as

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
```

Source: *[JavaScript: trim leading or trailing spaces from a string](http://www.toptip.ca/2010/02/javascript-trim-leading-or-trailing.html)*

Comment: No. `JSON.parse` handles whitespace just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function I made based on previous replies: it works on my machine but [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV#Phrase).

```
/**
   * @description Converts a string response to an array of objects.
   * @param {string} string - The string you want to convert.
   * @returns {array} - an array of objects.
  */
function stringToJson(input) {
  var result = [];

  // Replace leading and trailing [], if present
  input = input.replace(/^\[/, '');
  input = input.replace(/\]$/, '');

  // Change the delimiter to
  input = input.replace(/},{/g, '};;;{');

  // Preserve newlines, etc. - use valid JSON
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432165/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-with-json-parse
  input = input.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");

  // Remove non-printable and other non-valid JSON characters
  input = input.replace(/[\u0000-\u0019]+/g, "");

  input = input.split(';;;');

  input.forEach(function(element) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(element));

    result.push(JSON.parse(element));
  }, this);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only mistake is you are parsing an already-parsed object, so it's throwing an error. Use this and you will be good to go.

```js
var products = [{
  "name": "Pizza",
  "price": "10",
  "quantity": "7"
}, {
  "name": "Cerveja",
  "price": "12",
  "quantity": "5"
}, {
  "name": "Hamburguer",
  "price": "10",
  "quantity": "2"
}, {
  "name": "Fraldas",
  "price": "6",
  "quantity": "2"
}];
console.log(products[0].name); // Name of item at 0th index
```

If you want to print the entire JSON content, use JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 2):

One other gotcha that can result in `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token"` exception when calling `JSON.parse()` is using any of the following in the string values:

1. New-line characters.
2. Tabs (yes, tabs that you can produce with the Tab key!)
3. Any stand-alone slash `\` (but for some reason not `/`, at least not on Chrome.)

(For a full list see the [String section here](http://www.json.org/).)

For instance the following will get you this exception:

```
{
    "msg" : {
        "message": "It cannot
contain a new-line",
        "description": "Some discription with a     tabbed space is also bad",
        "value": "It cannot have 3\4 un-escaped"
    }
}
```

So it should be changed to:

```
{
    "msg" : {
        "message": "It cannot\ncontain a new-line",
        "description": "Some discription with a\t\ttabbed space",
        "value": "It cannot have 3\\4 un-escaped"
    }
}
```

Which, I should say, makes it quite unreadable in JSON-only format with larger amount of text.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had commented HTML in a [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) callback function via [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) that was parsing the comments and return invalid JSON.

Once I removed the commented HTML, all was good and the JSON was parsed without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

*products* is an array which can be used directly:

```
var i, j;

for(i=0; i<products.length; i++)
  for(j in products[i])
    console.log("property name: " + j, "value: " + products[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) or [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) method, make sure to stringify the body part.

I have documented an example here at
https://gist.github.com/manju16832003/4a92a2be693a8fda7ca84b58b8fa7154

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pizza",
    "price": "10",
    "quantity": "7"
  },
  {
    "name": "Cerveja",
    "price": "12",
    "quantity": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hamburguer",
    "price": "10",
    "quantity": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Fraldas",
    "price": "6",
    "quantity": "2"
  }
]
```

---

Here is your perfect JSON content that you can parse.

Answer (score 0):

Now apparently `\r`, `\b`, `\t`, `\f`, etc. aren't the only problematic characters that can give you this error.

Note that some browsers may have *additional* requirements for the input of `JSON.parse`.

Run this test code in your browser:

```
var arr = [];
for(var x=0; x < 0xffff; ++x){
    try{
        JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode(0x22, x, 0x22));
    }catch(e){
        arr.push(x);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Testing on Chrome, I see that it doesn't allow `JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode(0x22, x, 0x22));` where `x` is 34, 92, or from 0 to 31.

Characters 34 and 92 are the `"` and `\` characters respectively, and they are usually expected and properly escaped. It's characterss 0 to 31 that would give you problems.

To help with debugging, before you do `JSON.parse(input)`, first verify that the input doesn't contain problematic characters:

```
function VerifyInput(input){
    for(var x=0; x<input.length; ++x){
        let c = input.charCodeAt(x);
        if(c >= 0 && c <= 31){
            throw 'problematic character found at position ' + x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting, i.e., "unexpected token o", is because JSON is expected, but an object is obtained while parsing. That "o" is the first letter of word "object".

Answer (score 0):

It can happen for a lot of reasons, but probably for an invalid character, so you can use `JSON.stringify(obj);` that will turn your object into a JSON, but remember that it is a jQuery expression.

Comment: Don't understand what jQuery has to do with your answer? `JSON.stringify` is a JS native API

Answer (score 0):

In my case there are the following character problems in my JSON string:

1. \r
2. \t
3. \r\n
4. \n
5. :
6. "

I have replaced them with other characters or symbols, and then reverted back again from coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is now a JavaScript array of objects, not JSON format. To convert it into JSON format, you need to use a function called **JSON.stringify()**.

```
JSON.stringify(products)
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need *JSON.parse*? It's already in an array-of-object format.

Better use JSON.stringify as below:

`var b = JSON.stringify(products);`

Answer (score -1):

Oh man, solutions in all previous answers didn't work for me.  I had a similar problem just now.  I managed to solve it with wrapping with the quote. See the screenshot. Whoo.

[image]

**Original:**

```js
var products = [{
  "name": "Pizza",
  "price": "10",
  "quantity": "7"
}, {
  "name": "Cerveja",
  "price": "12",
  "quantity": "5"
}, {
  "name": "Hamburguer",
  "price": "10",
  "quantity": "2"
}, {
  "name": "Fraldas",
  "price": "6",
  "quantity": "2"
}];
console.log(products);
var b = JSON.parse(products); //unexpected token o
```

Comment: You didnt solve it, you just made the whole thing a string

Comment: Didn't think that time. Brain can't work. Thank you @NotSoShabby

Answer (score -1):

The mistake I was doing was passing `null` (unknowingly) into JSON.parse().

So it threw *Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0*.

But this happens whenever you pass something which is not a JavaScript Object in JSON.parse().

Answer (score -26):

Use `eval`. It takes JavaScript expression/code as string and evaluates/executes it.

```
eval(inputString);
```

Comment: Each invocation of eval() creates a new instance of the JavaScript interpreter. This can be a resource hog.

Comment: This was the ONLY option that worked for me. Thanks

Comment: usage of eval is highly discouraged, especially if you retrieve your data through an api, since it will leave you vulnrable to security issues and malicious attacks