# react-rails with jbuilder doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jbuilder, react-rails

I try to use `react-rails` with jbuilder.
For example, I use [this great sample app of react-rails](https://github.com/bensmithett/sample-react-rails-app) and try to rewrite to use jbuilder as a json response using reference from [this part](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#jbuilder--react-rails) in `react-rails`.

These are the main rewrite parts:

```rb
# app/views/comments/index.html.erb
<%= react_component 'CommentBox', render(template: 'comments/index.json.jbuilder'), {prerender: true} %>
```

```rb
# app/views/comments/index.json.jbuilder
json.presenter do
  json.comments(@comments) do |comment|
    json.extract! comment, :id, :author
  end
  json.form do
    json.action comments_path
    json.csrf_param request_forgery_protection_token
    json.csrf_token form_authenticity_token
  end
end
json.imgSrc image_path("gundam.jpg")
```

But I got an following error:

```
Started GET "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-07 18:26:40 +0900
Processing by CommentsController#index as HTML
  Comment Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"   ORDER BY "comments"."id" DESC LIMIT 5
  Rendered comments/index.json.jbuilder (8.4ms)
  Rendered comments/index.html.erb within layouts/application (34.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms

ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token o):
  app/views/comments/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_comments_index_html_erb___3472795088323540071_70123597415980'
```

Do you have any idea to solve this error?
Thanks in advance.

see full source code:
[Use jbuilder but it gets an error · jwako/sample-react-rails-app@508d581](https://github.com/jwako/sample-react-rails-app/commit/508d5815e17ce698a9ecde4fce796c0ca7096ff5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the unexpected token is raised because the CommentBox component is calling [`JSON.parse()` in `getInitialState`](https://github.com/jwako/sample-react-rails-app/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/react_components/_comment_box.js.jsx#L3) when `this.props.presenter` is already a JSON object.

You can fix it by removing `JSON.parse()` in `getInitialState` and returning only `this.props.presenter`.

Here is a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14432182) on parsing existing JSON objects.