# JSON format is valid. Json.Parse throws error

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

Below is my JSON format:

```
{
    "Heading": "Issue",
    "HeadingCtnt": "testit",
    "Cause": "",
    "SecHeading": "Workaround",
    "SecHeadingCtnt": "",
    "AddInfo": ""
}
```

My code to parse JSON:

```
data = JSON.parse(content);
```

Even though its a valid JSON, I am getting an error as below:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is already in JSON format and not string.

Comment: But there is no < in that JSON string . Are you sure youre parsing the right variable?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stack sippet?

Comment: There is no `<` character in the JSON you posted to clearly you didn't post exactly what you're trying to paste. Did you `console.log` it and look at it? I bet you got an HTTP error and you're trying to parse an HTML error page or something.

Comment: Its in JSON format only, you don't need to parse it again

Comment: Using jQuery, how can I check if a JSON is valid ?

Comment: To make your question more clear you should show the initialization of `content`. Though Srini's answer should work for you.

Comment: [Did you try this solution ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432165/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-with-json-parse)

Answer (score 1):

In your post content is a javascript object. You have to convert it to string as json parser takes only string.

Update your json by adding single quotes as shown below.

```
var content = 
'{"Heading": "Issue", "HeadingCtnt": "testit","Cause": "","SecHeading":"Workaround","SecHeadingCtnt":"" ,"AddInfo": ""}';
```