# Error parsing JSON string using parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, fusioncharts

Need some help if there is a problem with the code or the data itself. Although I suspect its with the code because I tried to validate the JSON data I received it is properly formatted...

Here is my JSON data

```
{"view":"cities","model":{"top10Cities":[{"id":1024,"name":"Mumbai (Bombay)","countrycode":"IND","district":"Maharashtra","population":"10500000"},{"id":2331,"name":"Seoul","countrycode":"KOR","district":"Seoul","population":"9981619"},{"id":206,"name":"São Paulo","countrycode":"BRA","district":"São Paulo","population":"9968485"},{"id":1890,"name":"Shanghai","countrycode":"CHN","district":"Shanghai","population":"9696300"},{"id":939,"name":"Jakarta","countrycode":"IDN","district":"Jakarta Raya","population":"9604900"},{"id":2822,"name":"Karachi","countrycode":"PAK","district":"Sindh","population":"9269265"},{"id":3357,"name":"Istanbul","countrycode":"TUR","district":"Istanbul","population":"8787958"},{"id":2515,"name":"Ciudad de México","countrycode":"MEX","district":"Distrito Federal","population":"8591309"},{"id":3580,"name":"Moscow","countrycode":"RUS","district":"Moscow (City)","population":"8389200"},{"id":3793,"name":"New York","countrycode":"USA","district":"New York","population":"8008278"}],"fusionCharts":{"chart":"{\"showValues\":\"0\",\"caption\":\"Cities by Country Code\",\"theme\":\"zune\"}","data":"[{\"label\":\"Mumbai (Bombay)\",\"value\":\"10500000\"},{\"label\":\"Seoul\",\"value\":\"9981619\"},{\"label\":\"São Paulo\",\"value\":\"9968485\"},{\"label\":\"Shanghai\",\"value\":\"9696300\"},{\"label\":\"Jakarta\",\"value\":\"9604900\"},{\"label\":\"Karachi\",\"value\":\"9269265\"},{\"label\":\"Istanbul\",\"value\":\"8787958\"},{\"label\":\"Ciudad de México\",\"value\":\"8591309\"},{\"label\":\"Moscow\",\"value\":\"8389200\"},{\"label\":\"New York\",\"value\":\"8008278\"}]"}},"cleared":false}
```

Here is the code I used to receive the JSON data

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var jsonD = $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/v1/cityData", function ( data ) {
        console.log("Success "+ data.toString());
        alert(data);

        $("#fChart").insertFusionCharts({
            type: "column2d",
            width: "450",
            height: "250",
            dateFormat: "JSONURL",
            dataSource: data
        });
    })

});
```

I tried the tips stated on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432165/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-with-json-parse) but its still not working. Any advice on how to fix this? Thanks

## Update 2

modified jquery code as suggested by Nisanth but the chart library is still not working. It says invalid data, maybe this is a problem with fusion charts library itself?

```
    $(document).ready( function () {

var jsonD = {};

        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/v1/cityData", function ( data ) {

            console.log("Success ");
            alert(data);
            jsonD = data;

        }).done( function () {

            var fcData = JSON.stringify(jsonD);
            console.log("fcData: "+fcData);
            $("#fChart").insertFusionCharts({
                type: "column2d",
                width: "450",
                height: "250",
                dateFormat: "JSON",
                dataSource: fcData
            });
        });     
    });
```

The code is working fine i've added a log inside .done function and it showed the value of fcData see below.

[image]

Changed fcData = jsonD.model.fusionCharts and received the error below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.match is not a function
    at Fb (fusioncharts.js:214)
    at constructor._drawCategory (fusioncharts.js:1263)
    at constructor._drawComponents (fusioncharts.js:1223)
    at constructor.draw (fusioncharts.js:1220)
    at k._drawAxis (fusioncharts.js:981)
    at k._updateVisuals (fusioncharts.js:976)
    at k.draw (fusioncharts.js:979)
    at k.init (fusioncharts.js:946)
    at Object.m.createChart (fusioncharts.js:875)
    at n.core.render (fusioncharts.js:1801)
```

## Update 3

Code update

```
    }).done( function () {          
        var cfChart= jsonD.model.fusionCharts.chart;
        var cfData= jsonD.model.fusionCharts.chart;
        $("#fChart").insertFusionCharts({
             type: "column2d",
             width: "450",
             height: "250",
             dateFormat: "JSON",
            dataSource: {chart:cfChart,data:cfData}
         });
    });     
});
```

Error Log

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.match is not a function
    at Fb (fusioncharts.js:214)
    at constructor._drawCategory (fusioncharts.js:1263)
    at constructor._drawComponents (fusioncharts.js:1223)
    at constructor.draw (fusioncharts.js:1220)
    at k._drawAxis (fusioncharts.js:981)
    at k._updateVisuals (fusioncharts.js:976)
    at k.draw (fusioncharts.js:979)
    at k.init (fusioncharts.js:946)
    at Object.m.createChart (fusioncharts.js:875)
    at n.core.render (fusioncharts.js:1801)
```

## Working code

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var jsonD = {};

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/v1/cityData", function ( data ) {

        console.log("Success ");
        //alert(data);
        jsonD = data;

    }).done( function () {

        var cfChart= JSON.parse(jsonD.model.fusionCharts.chart);
        var cfData= JSON.parse(jsonD.model.fusionCharts.data);
        $("#fChart").insertFusionCharts({
             type: "column2d",
             width: "450",
             height: "250",
             dateFormat: "JSON",
            dataSource: {chart:cfChart,data:cfData}
         });
    });     
});
```

Comment: The `$.getJSON()` function doesn't return the JSON string, it passes it to your callback function in the `data` argument. Call `.insertFusioncharts()` from inside the `$.getJSON()` callback, using `data` - noting that jQuery will have already parsed the JSON for you.

Comment: @nnnnnnn i still receive the same message "[object Object] " after I moved it inside $.getJSON check my update.

Comment: @dimas you aren't convertng json to string. Do: `var fcData = JSON.stringify(jsonD);`

Comment: `"[object Object]"` is what I'd expect to see in the console when you call `.toString()` on it (use `console.log(data)` instead), but does the actual chart work? I'm not familiar with that charting tool, but the other charting libraries that I've used expect the data as an array/object, not as a JSON string, and `data` will already be an object after jQuery automatically parsed your JSON.

Comment: @nishanth and nnnnnn i was just trying it out see if it works. Anyway i tried the code you have suggested but the chart still doesn't work. I am using fusioncharts library. It says Invalid data, maybe this is a problem with the library itself?

Comment: chart is still not working, modified dateFormat: "JSON" as you have suggested please see my update.

Comment: @NishanthMatha the chart canvas is now showing but there is no data and there is an error in the console

Comment: @dimas try my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @nnnnnn mentioned in his comment... `$.getJSON` doesn't return a `json`. It always returns a `Deferred Object`.

If you want to use the `data` of `$.getJSON` success function you could do:

```
//declaring in global scope
var jsonD={};
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/v1/cityData", function ( data ) {
    console.log("Success");
    alert(data);
    //changing the value in local scope
    jsonD = data;
}).done(function(){
        var fcData = jsonD.model.fusionCharts;
        $("#fChart").insertFusionCharts({
             type: "column2d",
             width: "450",
             height: "250",
             dateFormat: "JSON",
            dataSource: fcData
         });
 })
```

***EDIT***

After inspecting your `json` data I see the data isn't extracted properly. `FusionCharts` expect theJSON data to have `chart` and `data` keys. This data is present in your `JSON` inside `data.model.fusionCharts` as `string`

So, you have to first `extract` them then parse it to `json` and then supply it to your `dataSource`.

So, you're actual `fusionChart` set up would be something like:

```
.done(function(){
            var cfChart= JSON.parse(jsonD.model.fusionCharts.chart);
            var cfData= JSON.parse(jsonD.model.fusionCharts.data);
            $("#fChart").insertFusionCharts({
                 type: "column2d",
                 width: "450",
                 height: "250",
                 dateFormat: "JSON",
                dataSource: {chart:cfChart,data:cfData}
             });
     })
```

Comment: i still received an error after applying the suggestions you did... I've updated my code and posted the error.

Comment: there was a typo..check the recent update and try it!

Comment: Now the chart is showing up! thank you very much! wish i could add more points to this answer. Although am a bit confused now as to what you did in the data source part.

Comment: ok what I did in `dataSource` is two steps: 1) I did extract the `chart` part from your JSON data by doing `jsonD.model.fusionCharts.chart` . Then this is tring and Fusion chart expects JSON so I have to convert to json by doing `JSON.parse(<<extracted part>>)` 2) I did the same with `data` extracted it and then parsed it to JSON.

Comment: finally, I'm creating a new object...with 1) `chart` as key and value as `info extracted and parsed from jsonD.model.fusionCharts.chart`  2) with `data` as key and value as `info extracted and parsed from jsonD.model.fusionCharts.data` and passing it to `dataSource` using  the syntax `dataSource: {chart:cfChart,data:cfData}`

Comment: ok i think I got it now but it really requires some deep understanding of javascript which i still require. Another thing i noticed you only extracted fusioncharts portion of the json data but I don't think the view and model part is not needed is that correct? If yes would it be safe if I somehow modify the rest data am publishing in the backend?

Comment: @dimas absolutely yes. There is no need for other data just pass `jsonD.model.fusionCharts` (`fusionCharts` part which is present in `model`) part from the backend. It will make your code and life much easier :)