# Convert JSON response to Google Sheet ( Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have been trying to figure out to insert the JSON response into google Sheet in Google Apps Script with below code but for some reason I am getting error while trying to run.

please see screenshot and below code.

```
    function myFunction() {

  var key_67 = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
  var ss_67 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key_67);
  var sheet_67 = ss_67.getActiveSheet();
  sheet_67.getRange('A1:AZ10000').clearContent();
 var url = 'https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/arfater/view/Leads_Report?authtoken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=creatorapi&zc_ownername=ipekuet';
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Logger.log(data);



  var stats=[]; //create empty array to hold data points



  //The following lines push the parsed json into empty stats array

    stats.push(data.Yearly_Sales); //temp
    stats.push(data.Email); //dewPoint
    stats.push(data.Phone); //visibility

  //append the stats array to the active sheet 
  sheet_67.appendRow(stats)

}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you Logger.log(json) before you put it through JSON.parse()?

Comment: Ruben - Thanks for your reply.. I tried what you have suggested but getting same error .. here is what I tried with                                       
`var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
Logger.log(json);
var data = JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: error : **SyntaxError: Unexpected token: v (line 11, file "ConvertoCSVFromJSON")**

Comment: Here is the API response for your convenience `{
  "Leads": [
    {
      "Yearly_Sales": "$ 1,000.00",
      "Email": "test12@zoho.com",
      "Phone": "123-032-03323",
      "Potentially": 50,
      "State": "NY",
      "ZipCode": "10021",
      "Street": "11 Penn Plz",
      "Country": "USA",
      "ID": "2198633000000063039",
      "City": "New York",
      "Name": "Shafater Rahman"
    } 
  ]
}`

Comment: I am not totally sure, but it looks like the response is already a JSON object and you don't need to run it through JSON.parse() because JSON.parse() expects a string. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432165/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-with-json-parse

Comment: Here is what I get response when I call API from "postman" (Chrome Extension) ----------                                                                                  `var zohoipekuetview65 = {"Leads":[{"Yearly_Sales":"$ 1,000.00","Email":"test@zoho.com","Phone":"123-032-03323","Potentially":50,"State":"NY","ZipCode":"10036","Street":"1515 Broadway","Country":"USA","ID":"2198633000000063029","City":"New York","Name":"Arfater Rahman"}]};`

Comment: when I run below code there is no error but no row have been saved in Google Sheet except "Undefined" in each cell   `function myFunction() {
  ......// truncated some initial code
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
  Logger.log(data);
    var stats=[]; //create empty array to hold data points
  
     stats.push(data.Yearly_Sales); 
    stats.push(data.Email); 
    stats.push(data.Phone); 
    
 sheet_67.appendRow(stats)
 }`

Answer (score 1):

So your JSON response based on postman app is

`var zohoipekuetview65 = {"Leads":[{"Yearly_Sales":"$ 1,000.00","Email":"test@zoho.com","Phone":"123-032-03323","P‌otentially":50,"Stat‌e":"NY","ZipCode":"1‌​0036","Street":"1515 Broadway","Country":"USA","ID":"2198633000000063029","City":‌​"New York","Name":"Arfater Rahman"}]};`

When I use that response as is:

```
function JsonResponse(){
 var json ='var zohoipekuetview65 = {"Leads":[{"Yearly_Sales":"$ 1,000.00","Email":"test@zoho.com","Phone":"123-032-03323","P‌​otentially":50,"Stat‌​e":"NY","ZipCode":"1‌​0036","Street":"1515 Broadway","Country":"USA","ID":"2198633000000063029","City":‌​"New York","Name":"Arfater Rahman"}]} '
 var data = JSON.parse(json);
Logger.log(data); 
}
```

I get the same error as you:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token: v

Which leads me to believe your response from API has this term `var zohoipekuetview65` (Not really sure as to why? a bug perhaps)

The below code splits the response string to give you the JSON response only

```
function trialParse(){
var json ='var zohoipekuetview65 = {"Leads":[{"Yearly_Sales":"$ 1,000.00","Email":"test@zoho.com","Phone":"123-032-03323","P‌​otentially":50,"Stat‌​e":"NY","ZipCode":"1‌​0036","Street":"1515 Broadway","Country":"USA","ID":"2198633000000063029","City":‌​"New York","Name":"Arfater Rahman"}]} '
Logger.log(JsonResponse(json))
}
function JsonResponse(response){
  Logger.log(response)
  var json = response.split("=")[1]
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data);
  return data  
}
```

Just call the above function in your code using `var data = JsonResponse(json)`

Final Note: As mentioned by Jordan Rhea you can use `Logger.log(json)` to output the response to your logs. To view your logs goto Views>Logs, it will show you the response you receive from Api.