# SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

I'm trying to compile and migrate a solidity code built in an older version of solidity, using a newer solidity. This is the solidity code:

```
//solium-disable linebreak-style
    pragma solidity ^ 0.4 .23;

    // Simple Solidity intro/demo contract for BlockGeeks Article
    contract Geekt {

      address GeektAdmin;

      mapping(bytes32 => notarizedImage) notarizedImages; // this allows to look up notarizedImages by their SHA256notaryHash
      bytes32[] imagesByNotaryHash; // this is like a whitepages of all images, by SHA256notaryHash

      mapping(address => User) Users; // this allows to look up Users by their ethereum address
      address[] usersByAddress; // this is like a whitepages of all users, by ethereum address

      struct notarizedImage {
        string imageURL;
        uint timeStamp;
      }

      struct User {
        string handle;
        bytes32 city;
        bytes32 state;
        bytes32 country;
        bytes32[] myImages;
      }

      constructor() public payable {
        // this is the CONSTRUCTOR (same name as contract) it gets called ONCE only when contract is first deployed
        GeektAdmin = msg.sender; // just set the admin, so they can remove bad users or images if needed, but nobody else can
      }

      modifier onlyAdmin() {
        if (msg.sender != GeektAdmin)
          revert("invalid message sender: sender not admin");
        // Do not forget the "_;"! It will be replaced by the actual function body when the modifier is used.
        _;
      }

      function removeUser(address badUser) public onlyAdmin returns(bool success) {
        delete Users[badUser];
        return true;
      }

      function removeImage(bytes32 badImage) public onlyAdmin returns(bool success) {
        delete notarizedImages[badImage];
        return true;
      }

      function registerNewUser(string handle, bytes32 city, bytes32 state, bytes32 country) public returns(bool success) {
        address thisNewAddress = msg.sender;
        // don't overwrite existing entries, and make sure handle isn't null
        if (bytes(Users[msg.sender].handle).length == 0 && bytes(handle).length != 0) {
          Users[thisNewAddress].handle = handle;
          Users[thisNewAddress].city = city;
          Users[thisNewAddress].state = state;
          Users[thisNewAddress].country = country;
          usersByAddress.push(thisNewAddress); // adds an entry for this user to the user 'whitepages'
          return true;
        } else {
          return false; // either handle was null, or a user with this handle already existed
        }
      }

      function addImageToUser(string imageURL, bytes32 SHA256notaryHash) public returns(bool success) {
        address thisNewAddress = msg.sender;
        if (bytes(Users[thisNewAddress].handle).length != 0) { // make sure this user has created an account first
          if (bytes(imageURL).length != 0) { // ) {  // couldn't get bytes32 null check to work, oh well!
            // prevent users from fighting over sha->image listings in the whitepages, but still allow them to add a personal ref to any sha
            if (bytes(notarizedImages[SHA256notaryHash].imageURL).length == 0) {
              imagesByNotaryHash.push(SHA256notaryHash); // adds entry for this image to our image whitepages
            }
            notarizedImages[SHA256notaryHash].imageURL = imageURL;
            notarizedImages[SHA256notaryHash].timeStamp = block.number;
            // note that updating an image also updates the timestamp
            Users[thisNewAddress].myImages.push(SHA256notaryHash); // add the image hash to this users .myImages array
            return true;
          } else {
            return false; // either imageURL or SHA256notaryHash was null, couldn't store image
          }
          return true;
        } else {
          return false; // user didn't have an account yet, couldn't store image
        }
      }

      function getUsers() public view returns(address[]) {
        return usersByAddress;
      }

      function getUser(address userAddress) public view returns(string, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, bytes32[]) {
        return (Users[userAddress].handle, Users[userAddress].city, Users[userAddress].state, Users[userAddress].country, Users[userAddress].myImages);
      }

      function getAllImages() public view returns(bytes32[]) {
        return imagesByNotaryHash;
      }

      function getUserImages(address userAddress) public view returns(bytes32[]) {
        return Users[userAddress].myImages;
      }

      function getImage(bytes32 SHA256notaryHash) public view returns(string, uint) {
        return (notarizedImages[SHA256notaryHash].imageURL, notarizedImages[SHA256notaryHash].timeStamp);
      }

    }
```

This is the complete error log showing:

```
> Using network 'development'.
> 
> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
> 
> C:\Users\Kombos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:101723
>     var artifact = JSON.parse(
>                         ^ undefined:1 [.ShellClassInfo]  ^
> 
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 1
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at FS.getContractName (C:\Users\Kombos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:101723:25)
>     at FS.require (C:\Users\Kombos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:101698:28)
>     at Resolver.require (C:\Users\Kombos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:59966:25)
>     at Object.require (C:\Users\Kombos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:69602:36)
>     at ResolverIntercept.require (C:\Users\Kombos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:197047:32)
>     at D:\Cloud\Google Drive\Knowledge Base\Blockchain\Bitcoin\Blockchain Specialization\Smart
> Contracts\Project 1 - Image based Social
> app\Geek\migrations\1_initial_migration.js:1:28
>     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:59:29)
>     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:65:15)
>     at C:\Users\Kombos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:101639:14
>     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

could you please let me know what the error could be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting your `build` folder and start over, you might have leftover files from previous builds.

Comment: yup, that did it! Thanks a lot its working now! cant imagine a step which looks so obscure could cause such error! ... thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 1` exception happen probably for invalid chars in JSON

[already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730876/10611836)