# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.min.js:4 - AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My PHP

```
<?php
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$word = $_POST['word'];
function strProper($str) {
    $noUp = array('a','an','of','the','are','at','in');
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = strtoupper($str[0]) . strtolower(substr($str, 1));
    for($i=1; $i<strlen($str)-1; ++$i) {
        if($str[$i]==' ') {
            for($j=$i+1; $j<strlen($str) && $str[$j]!=' '; ++$j); //find next space
            $size = $j-$i-1;
            $shortWord = false;
            if($size<=1000) {
                $theWord = substr($str,$i+1,$size);
                for($j=0; $j<count($noUp) && !$shortWord; ++$j)
                    if($theWord==$noUp[$j])
                        $shortWord = true;
            } else{
                $str = substr($str, 0, $i+1) . strtoupper($str[$i+1]) . substr($str, $i+2);
            }
        }   
        $i+=$size;
    }
    return $str;
}
if(file_exists("$from-$to.txt")){
    $file = file("$from-$to.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
} else{
    $file = null;
}
$array = array();
$return = array();

if($file != null){
    foreach($file as $line){
        if(!empty($line)){
            $words = explode("=", $line);
            $results = explode("|", $words[1]);
            $rest = explode("|", $words[1]);
            array_shift($rest);
            $array[$words[0]] = $results[0];
            $final = strProper(strtr(strtolower($word), $array));
            $final = trim($final);
        } else{
            $final = null;
        }
    }
    $return['final'] = $final;
    $return['others'] = $rest;
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

My AJAX Call:

```
$("#translate_word").keyup(function(e){
            var from = $("#translate_from").val();
            var to = $("#translate_to").val();
            $("#translate_result").html($(this).val());
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "translate.php", 
                data: {word: $(this).val(), from: from, to: to},
                success: function(html){
                    if(html !== ""){
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(html);
                        console.log(obj);
                        $("#translate_result").text(obj.final);
                        if(typeof obj.others === 'object'){
                            $.each(obj.others, function(index, val){
                                $("#translate_others").html($("#translate_others").html() + val + "<br />");
                            });
                        } else{
                            $("#translate_others").html($("#translate_others").html() + obj.others + "<br />");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

But when I run the function it says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.min.js:4
>      n.parseJSON jquery.min.js:4
>      $.ajax.success (index):135
>      j jquery.min.js:2
>      k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
>      x jquery.min.js:4
>      b

But whenever I remove the function `strProper` from the PHP on line 43 it doesn't throw the error and everything works.

Comment: add `dataType: 'JSON'` to ajax option if you are expecting JSON, the server will return data in JSON format

Comment: depending on browser compatibility you might want to change @satpal's suggestion from json to jsonp

Comment: @Satpal Then it says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery.min.js:4

Comment: Can you show the part where you reference your scripts at the start of your html markup

Comment: @DWolf Then it doesn't do anything at all

Comment: @Dumisani <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="jquery.zclip.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="controls/tipr.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="controls/keyboard.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link type="text/css" href="controls/tipr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link type="text/css" href="controls/keyboard.style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: possible duplicate of [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)

Comment: Try `data: JSON.parse({word: $(this).val(), from: from, to: to}),`

Comment: @user3588664 — Really? You did say: *Then it says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery.min.js:4*

Comment: type is a POST but dataType: jsonp ...

Comment: The answers there didn't work for me @Quentin

Comment: @Dumisani It didn't work

Comment: @DWolf It didn't work