# unable to parse the JSON returned by AWS.EC2.describeInstances() method in nodejs API

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

This is my code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-1';

var uuid = require('node-uuid');
ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: 'latest'});


AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: xxxxxxxx, secretAccessKey: yyyyyyyyyyy});
AWS.config.update({region: 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz'});

var util = require('util');
var opsworks = new AWS.OpsWorks();
var cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

function listInstances(callback){
new AWS.EC2().describeInstances(function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    } else {
        callback(util.inspect(data, {depth: null})); //this returns a full fledged JSON response on the console

}

});
}

//Test above methods
listInstances(callback);


function callback(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

I tried parsing the JSON response by replacing the line

```
callback(util.inspect(data, {depth: null}));
```

with

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

I get the following error

```
{ [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o] statusCode: 200, retryable: false }
{ [200: null]
message: null,
code: 200,
time: Tue Jul 22 2014 22:59:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
statusCode: 200,
retryable: false }
```

i tried using eval() to parse it and i got the following error

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier]
```

Am I doing anything wrong, should I be parsing the JSON response using any other logic?

Please excuse my ignorance if any since I am new to both node.js and AWS

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` so we can see how it looks?

Comment: this is how it looks
{ Reservations:
   [ { ReservationId: 'xx2',
       OwnerId: 'xxx',
       Groups: [],
       Instances: [Object] },
     { ReservationId: 'xxx1',
       OwnerId: 'xxx',
       Groups: [],
       Instances: [Object] } ] }

Comment: So it's already an object. There's no need to parse anything. Just use it as is.

Comment: i even tried the following so that the "objects" are further simplified

var respdata = util.inspect(data, {depth: null});
JSON.parse(respdata);

even then it showed the same error

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There is no need to call `JSON.parse` -- you are already holding an object. Just do `data.Reservations[0].OwnerId`, for example.

Comment: @nitzan : that worked.. Seems like a silly question that i asked.. But i hope u can excuse it since i am very new to JavaScript.. Thanks a lot for your time..

Comment: no problems, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you do not need to parse data, because it is already parsed.

Look at this answer, it is a similar problem.

[I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)