# Angularjs error when pass object to get method and spring rest controller on back-end

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ajax, spring-mvc

I try to create registration form and pass data for rest server for do registration, but I get this error only  `angular.js:11607 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o ...`

controller:

```
$scope.signIn = function(){
    console.log($scope.ruser); // Object {username: "test@email.com",   password: "password"}
    $http.get('p/registration', $scope.ruser).success(function(data) {

    });
}
```

spring rest controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/p/registration")
 public String user(com.app.objects.users.User user) {
    System.out.println(user.getUsername()+" "+user.getPassword()); //print: null null :{
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: Invalid JSON format in respose?

Comment: Thanks, my response from server is single string "ok".

Comment: Then it should be in JSON format. Use `JSON.stringify` if NodeJS or `json_encode` if PHP

Comment: I use java spring rest controller on server side. Look to post.

Comment: when you get this method? defore send or on response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)

Comment: I try use it `ng-submit="signIn()"` on my registration form. I feel problem is on front-end while parsing ruser object to json before sending because server prints nulls on controller .

Comment: Shouldn't be $http.post insetead of $http.get, as you don't want to pass those values on query string?

Comment: No difference or post or get I get some SyntaxError.