# gem install jquery-colorpicker-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used this command to install gems for my rails project 
and I added following in `application.js`

```
require jquery-ui
require jquery-colorpicker
```

This gave error:

> could not find file 'jquery-colorpicker'

this is the code for **items/new.js.erb**

```
$('#dialog h3').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Add New Item");
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render("form") %>');
$('#dialog').modal("show");
$('#dialog').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
#   $('.colorpicker').focus()
    $('.colorpicker').colorpicker {autoOpen:true, hideOn:'button'}
})
```

Comment: did you use a gem for `jquery-colorpicker` ? where/how did you install it?

Comment: I used this command to install gem "gem install jquery-colorpicker-rails" when i added require statement for it in application.js i got the mentioned error

Comment: what is *this* command?

Comment: if `https://github.com/Ferroman/jquery-colorpicker-rails` is the gem you installed, then you need to `require jquery.ui.all` and `require jquery.colorpicker` (think README is missing the "r" there), like the README says

Comment: @dinjas this is for Rails version <4
I'm using Rails version >4 and for it i changed require jquery.ui.all to require jquery-ui and i don't know what will be the substitution for jquery.colorpicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-colorpicker-rails'
```

Add following to application.js

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-colorpicker
```

Hope, this helps!

Also, there is another gem `jquery-minicolors-rails` which embeds the **jQuery colorpicker** in the Rails asset pipeline. See: https://github.com/kostia/jquery-minicolors-rails

Comment: hey Thanks! can you tell me a way how i can use it on my input field?

Comment: I never used the gem `jquery-colorpicker-rails`. 

But I have used the gem `jquery-minicolors-rails`. Here is the documentation on how to use it: https://github.com/kostia/jquery-minicolors-rails#usage

Comment: Tried out `jquery-colorpicker-rails` just now. You text_field should look something like: `<%= f.text_field :pickcolor, class: 'colorpicker' %>` and the relevant coffee script should look something like: `$ -> $('.colorpicker').colorpicker {autoOpen:true, hideOn:'button'}`. You can further add more options listed at: https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker/#colorpickeroptions

Comment: jquery-minicolors-rails , I followed the documentation. Put the js code in my items.coffee file. But it is still not working, any idea? but the input filed on which I'm applying the function is in modal popup , will it make any difference?

Comment: I have added the code for new.js.erb 
I'm getting error 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token $"
what could be the reason for it?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference even if you are using a modal popup as long as the relevant js is loaded properly. Re: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token $" please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o#answer-8081745

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the gem itself into the gemfile.

Using gem install colorpicker will only install it on your local machine.