# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps-api-3

i have a problem about passing variable from controller to javascript

this is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $tourplace = Tourism::all();

    return view('spatialInfo')->with('tourplace',$tourplace);
}
```

this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var lokasi = [];
        var test = document.getElementsByName('kabupaten');

        var jsondata = JSON.parse({!! $tourplace !!});
        var htmlURL = '{{URL::to('/tourismplace/id/')}}';
        $.get(jsondata).success(function(data){
            var jumlahData = data.length;
            for(var i=0;i<jumlahData;i++){
                lokasi.push({
                    lat : data[i].latitude,
                    lon : data[i].longitude,
                    zoom : 15,
                    title : data[i].nama,
                    html : "<a href='"+htmlURL+"/"+data[i].id +"'>"+data[i].nama+"</a>",
                    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png', // custom icon
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse JSON with `JSON.parse()` use this code:

```
var jsondata = {!! $tourplace->toJson() !!};
```

`->toJson()` will convert Your collection to JSON, without needing to parse it again.

Comment: won't work, when i use it, it says "expression expected"

Comment: You are missing a declaration of variable.