# Django- jQuery AJAX POST response- trouble parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I'm using an app that allows me to post forms responses, from an html template, asynchronously. I've verified that my POST works fine, but I'm having trouble with the response. This is the main code for the corresponding Django view:

```
#views.py from the app........

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    published = Form.objects.published(for_user=request.user)
    form = get_object_or_404(published, slug=kwargs["slug"])
    form_for_form = FormForForm(form, RequestContext(request),
                                request.POST or None,
                                request.FILES or None)
    if not form_for_form.is_valid():
        form_invalid.send(sender=request, form=form_for_form)
    else:
        # Attachments read must occur before model save,
        # or seek() will fail on large uploads.
        attachments = []
        for f in form_for_form.files.values():
            f.seek(0)
            attachments.append((f.name, f.read()))
        entry = form_for_form.save()
        form_valid.send(sender=request, form=form_for_form, entry=entry)
        self.send_emails(request, form_for_form, form, entry, attachments)
        if not self.request.is_ajax():
            return redirect(form.redirect_url or
                reverse("form_sent", kwargs={"slug": form.slug}))
    context = {"form": form, "form_for_form": form_for_form}
    return self.render_to_response(context)

def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
    if self.request.method == "POST" and self.request.is_ajax():
        json_context = json.dumps({
            "errors": context["form_for_form"].errors,
            "form": context["form_for_form"].as_p(),
            "messag": context["form"].response,
        })
        if context["form_for_form"].errors:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(json_context,
                content_type="application/json")
        return HttpResponse(json_context, content_type="application/json")
    return super(FormDetail, self).render_to_response(context, **kwargs)
```

and this is the javascript part of my html template responsible for the post:

```
//My html template.....

<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#theform');
frm.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        data: frm.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('TESTING...');
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(json);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $("#responsediv").html("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So I can POST fine (I verified my submissions being correctly stored in the server side) but my problem lies in the `success: function (data)` part, as I'm having trouble parsing the json response. I've looked at many other questions about this and followed the tips people got, but I can't seem to be able to parse the json response. In this case, I get the alert for `alert('TESTING...');`, but `var json = $.parseJSON(data);` does not work, and the following alert does not happen.

I do not understand what the problem is. How to solve this issue?

I've confirmed that I'm in fact getting the json success response from the server, because if I try to print "data", I'll get `[object Object]`

In Chrome's console I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at Function.parse [as parseJSON] ()

Comment: Just to test it out, can you try `JSON.parse()` method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse. Also in `Developer Tools > Network > [XHR item in list] Preview` you should be able to see the parsed JSON in text format.

Comment: Could you just `console.log(data)` before parsing to json and look for output in `Developer Tools > Console` in Chrome?

Comment: Meanwhile I've found the answer just by looking for the error here, which I had forgotten to do. I appreciate you guys' comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake. By putting in `dataType: 'json',`  the json is already parsed, so I was effectively trying to parse it again when it was totally unnecessary. The 'solution' is here:

> [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)

I did not remember to look for the specific error I got before posting the question, I'm sorry. I just looked for generic questions about the Django AJAX POST returns.