# Angular 2 Http GET not passing Search Params

Tags: angular

Im trying make a http request with GET mephod passing params, but it's not working, request is calling the endpoint but not passing search params

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('dt_from', '2017-09-03');
params.set('dt_to', '2017-09-03');
return this.http.get(environment.apiHost + 'reports/report01', {search: params})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have forgotten to add import for `URLSearchParams`

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: @rayashi np,you can mark it if it works might help someone :)

Comment: @rayashi You should likely receive type error because of that. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43750374/3731501 . New HttpClient doesn't have this problem.