# How to set a header with http.get

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, angular2-http

I'm using Angular 4.4.4 and I need to set the `Authorization` header for a GET request. I've studied the docs and the code to figure out how to do this. This was the result:

```
const headers = new Headers({ Authorization: this.auth.accessToken});
this.http.get('/api/Messages', { headers } as RequestOptionsArgs)
```

However, this doesn't work. The request is made without the header option.

But if I do it as follows

```
const options = { headers: {Authorization: this.auth.accessToken} as any};

return this.http.get('/api/Messages', options as RequestOptionsArgs)
```

It works.

But I would expect the first attempt to work too. Can someone explain to me what is wrong with my first attempt or explain to me what the correct approach is?

Comment: I would also expect the first attempt to work. Are you using `@angular/http` or `@angular/common/http`?

Comment: I'm using `@angular/http`. The weird thing is that if I debug and step into the angular code I see very soon something like this: `this.headers = new Headers(requestOptions.headers);` but `requestOptions.headers` is already an instance of `Headers`. It doesn't make any sense

Comment: In the first one 'headers:' key is missing. You are assigning without the key {{ Authorization: this.auth.accessToken}} instead of {headers:{ Authorization: this.auth.accessToken}}

Comment: You mean that I do `{headers}` instead of `{headers: headers}`? But these two are identical in es2015/typescript

Comment: what if you strip the { } entirely and just pass in headers? I think newing up an angular Headers object gets you what you need to pass into the get function

Comment: Nope, doesn't fix it. I will try to make a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so you can see it in action, just a moment

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Are you certainly importing Headers?

Comment: Aren't `Headers` a browser thing ( [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Headers)) but I agree, I'm working on a demo (stackblitz) right now :)

Comment: Yes, they are, and considering that you're asking about that, that's the problem. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612837/error-when-unit-testing-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o . Symptoms are different but the problem is same.

Comment: You're right, its the Headers. Your suggestion fix the issue! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I submitted this as the answer, guess this will help somebody else because the problem is quite annoying yet subtle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612837/error-when-unit-testing-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o), the problem is that Fetch API has same class names as the classes from `@angular/http` module (their design is loosely based on Fetch API).

If Angular classes (Header, Response, etc) weren't imported, global classes are used instead. This results in incorrect behaviour and irrelevant errors, because Angular classes aren't compatible with Fetch API, yet `Http` isn't fool-proof.

The solution is to always import relevant classes together with `Http` (this can be done beforehand even if they aren't used):

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

A way to avoid the problem is to switch to `HttpClient` which is available in latest Angular 4 releases and has different API.