# Angular service method calling http get with URLSearchParams , but dont see querystring?

Tags: angular, angular-services

Im trying to use URLSearchParams to fill in querystring parameters and their values.  However, the resulting url that seems to get used on the http call doesnt look like its including any of the querystring info.  What am I doing wrong?  Im looking at the network tab on the chrome dev tools

```
getBlogPost(postId:string): Observable<BlogPost> {
     var myHeaders = new Headers();
     myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');        
     let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
     myParams.append('Id', postId);
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders, params: myParams });                  
     return this.http.get("http://myapi.testapp.com/api/gfNet/GetBlogPost",options)
         .map((res: Response) => res.json())
         .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

[ **update** ]
duh... this one of my import statements.  Notice Im missing something
that something is URLSearchParams
Once I added that with the others from the http module, things started working and the url querystring showed up

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when unit testing: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612837/error-when-unit-testing-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)