# Javascript - Read JSON fields that are formatted as urls

Tags: javascript, json, rest

A REST API sends me JSON back with URLs as fields.

How do I read these fields with Javascript?
This doesn't work...

```
var json = JSON.parse(profile);

console.log(json["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality"]);
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Strategy._verify (D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\server.js:33:21)
at validateCallback (D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\passport-saml\lib\passport-saml\strategy.js:61:14)
at D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\passport-saml\lib\passport-saml\saml.js:845:5
at _fulfilled (D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
at D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
at runSingle (D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
at flush (D:\Development\NodeJS\EID_TEST_NODEJS\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
```

JSON send back from the api:

```
{
"issuer":"www.econtract.be",
"nameID":"00081007501",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality":"Hasselt",
"be:fedict:eid:idp:card-validity:end":"2023-03-03T00:00:00Z",
"be:fedict:eid:idp:card-number":"592548451825",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier":"00081007501",
"be:fedict:eid:idp:nationality":"Belg",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/dateofbirth":"2000-08-10T00:00:00Z",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/gender":"1",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/postalcode":"3511",  
etc....
}
```

**Problem solved! Thanks @Mike**

Change this code:

```
var json = JSON.parse(profile);
console.log(json["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality"]);
```

To this code:

```
console.log(profile["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality"]);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try posting your JSON in a site like https://jsonlint.com/.  That will ensure that you are indeed receiving valid JSON.

Comment: You've got other problems besides that. Do a search on that error, and you'll find you're most likely parsing the JSON twice. Remember that JSON is a string format; check what `profile` is in a debugger and you'll likely find it's an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)

Comment: Your json is already an object. You try to parse an object not a json string.

Comment: It's valid json, I've tested it;

Comment: @Michiel So that narrows down that.  I think Mike may be right, calling parse on an already parsed object will throw that error.  If you remove the parse line, and access it on the profile, do you still see that error?

Comment: What is `typeof profile`?

Comment: It should ask you to accept the duplicate. Do that, and that'll be thanks enough :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation :**

You are trying to parse `JSON Object`. No need to parse JSON object again as it is already parsed while sending back from the API.

[image]

**Working Demo**

```js
var profile = {
"issuer":"www.econtract.be",
"nameID":"00081007501",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality":"Hasselt",
"be:fedict:eid:idp:card-validity:end":"2023-03-03T00:00:00Z",
"be:fedict:eid:idp:card-number":"592548451825",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier":"00081007501",
"be:fedict:eid:idp:nationality":"Belg",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/dateofbirth":"2000-08-10T00:00:00Z",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/gender":"1",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/postalcode":"3511"
};

console.log(profile["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality"]);
```