# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 when trying to access a field of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, signalr

The following is the json that I am receiving:

```
{
"total": 5,
"responses": [{
    "gender": "Female",
    "age": 66
}, {
    "gender": "Male",
    "age": 52
}]
}
```

The following is the code I am using to receive and parse the json

```
// Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
$.connection.hub.url = 'https://www.url...';
var res = $.connection.resHub;
// Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
res.client.broadcastRes = function (resp) {
 var now = new Date();
 console.log(now.toLocaleTimeString(), 'signalR survey data received', JSON.parse(resp));
 createChart(JSON.parse(resp.responses));
};
$.connection.hub.start();
```

In the console I am being able to see the entire JSON response like I showed above by doing `console.log(JSON.parse(resp));`

But I am getting the error

> Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()

When I am using `resp.responses`

Where am I going wrong?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: it is already a javascript object just don't parse it

Comment: `resp.responses` is `undefined` - hence the unexpected `u` as `undefined` gets stringified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)

Comment: Please, search for the error message before asking.

Comment: Check [**morgane1806 answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303106/448144) below. Even with lack of explanation it is most likely what you looking for.

Comment: Apologies, that was the incorrect duplicate. It should be [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0](//stackoverflow.com/q/46613243)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically, if `resp` is an string, then if you do `JSON.parse(resp.responses)` will fail because `responses` is `undefined`.

You just want `JSON.parse(resp).responses`. This contains the array you need

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `createChart(JSON.parse(resp).responses);`

Comment: Could you add some explanation? What went wrong before and what you did to fix it. This was flagged as a low quality answer