# Having trouble with JSON.parse with a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to parse this JSON output.

```
var text = [{"name":"bob","image":"bob.png"},{"name":"jim","image":"jim.png"}];
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj[0].name + ", " + obj[0].image;
```

The expected output would be:

> bob, bob.png

Comment: The `text` is not actually `text`, but an object; don't try to `parse` something that's already an object. Just use `Object.values(text[0])`

Comment: `var text = JSON.stringify([{name:"bob", image:"bob.png"}, {name:"jim", image: "jim.png"}]);` ...

Comment: You should be getting an error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" in your console. Searching for that yields [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8081701), which will tell you what the problem is. @Ele, I think that's probably a better dupe target since the OP is not actually parsing JSON.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, you're right, I wanted to address the OP to understand how the `JSON.parse` works.

Comment: First of all, You have to place the div ("demo") before the script, so that it exists when the script is loaded.Secondly, You have to stringify the **text** and you have to parse it. _DO not foget to place script after body tag_                                                                                                                                               `var text = [{"name":"bob","image":"bob.png"},{"name":"jim","image":"jim.png"}];
 var obj = JSON.stringify(text);
 obj = JSON.parse(obj);
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj[0].name + ", " + obj[0].image;`